# Post data using angularjs to a PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

how can i submit a form and pass post data to `angularjs`? I know it must be trivial task  but can not see my error.

That data will feed post variables in a `PHP` `API` that consume a `webservice` and return `JSON` and it is working when i do not use the search function.

I have `month` and `origin` to pass to a search function in the controller, and in the ApiAcp factory I have a resolve from the `url: q.resolve(data);`

When I do submit, the console log says: "cannot read `url` property of undefined", I can not see how to inject the Endpoint `url` into the search function properly, as the search without parameters works fine.

Here are the templates and the search button :

```
 <form method="post" ng-controller="AcpSearchCtrl" ng-submit="searchAcp(data)">
    <select name="month" ng-model="data.month">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    ...
 </select>

 <select name="origin" ng-model="data.origin">
    <option value="99">OneState</option>
    ...
     ...
 </select>
 <input type="button" ng-click="search(data)" value="Search"/>
```

In the Controller i try to create a search function wich is not working says cannot read property url of undefined  :

```
    .controller('AcpSearchCtrl', function($scope, ApiAcp, $timeout, $http, ApiAcpEndpoint, $q) {  
  $scope.searchAcp = function(data ) {
    $scope.month = data.month;
    $scope.origin = data.origin;
    var q = $q.defer();
    $http.post(ApiAcpEndpoint.url, data)
      .then(function(data) {      
          console.log(data);
          console.log(' - data.month '+data.month);
          console.log(' - data.origin '+data.origin);
          q.resolve(data);
          console.log(' q.promise '+q.promise);
          var acp = {};
          acp.dados = [ data ];      
          $scope.data = acp.dados;
          console.log('data :'+$scope.data);

          return q.promise;
      });
  }
})
```

In the Services.js i do post data and it works if i do not search by month or origin :

```
.factory('ApiAcp', function($http, $q, ApiAcpEndpoint) { 
  console.log('1. ApiAcpEndpoint url ', ApiAcpEndpoint.url)  

  var getApiData = function() {    
    var q = $q.defer();    
    $http.post(ApiAcpEndpoint.url)
    .success(function(data) {
      q.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(error){
      console.log('Had an error'+error)
      q.reject(error);
    })
    return q.promise;
  }
  return {
    getApiData: getApiData    
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApiAcpEndpoint should be injected in the controller definition/initialization, and not in $scope.search (same goes for $http)

```
.controller('AcpCtrl', function($scope, ApiAcp, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $http,  ApiAcpEndpoint) {
  $scope.data = null;
  ApiAcp.getApiData()
    .then(function(result) {      
      console.log(result);
      $scope.headers = ['Desc','Real. month', 'Real. year/month', 'Plan. year/month', 'Real. year'];
      var acp = {};
      $scope.data = acp.dados;
      console.log(' scope.data '+$scope.data);

   })

  $scope.search = function(data) {
    $http.post(ApiAcpEndpoint.url,data)
      .success(function(data){
        console.log(' data from : '+data);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pierre, it work´s for me! now when i submit the endpoint is reached, the only problem that remains is that the data is undefined

Comment: Which `data` is undefined? I see a few `data` variables :)

Comment: Is the data inside the search function. I change to a form submit : *ng-submit="search(data)* now the data appear at the console.log but seems that the form is not submited to the template as the data remains the same.

Comment: The fields month and origin bind correctly, i can see their values when i choose them at the template and also at the console.log but they does not modify the url of the webservice and the result is always the result of the actual month.

Comment: I do isolate the search into his own controller but still could not get the data